# v.clean (GRASS) creates additional features

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology, grass-7.0, v.clean

I am working with a large road dataset (approx. 1 million features) with a high number of overshoots and dangles.

To address the overshoots and dangles, I am using the v.clean tools (break, snap, rmdangle) with the -c flag to combine with follow-up tools. I have also selected only lines as the input feature type and added threshold values of 1 and 7 (ft) for snap and rmdangle.

After running this tool, the number of features increases by approximately 40,000. I am looking for clarity on the cause of these additional features.

I am under the impression that the break tool is primarily responsible for creating the extra features. What I am not clear on is exactly what format these extra features are in and why they are being created. I am assuming each segment of the break becomes a new feature? But in that case, how are original feature attributes handled? For instance, I have a segment length attribute and a travel time attribute, and it is important that the integrity of those attributes remain in the cleaned dataset. In addition, I have noticed that changing the threshold value on snap also changes the number of features, and I am unclear why that would be.

In addition, from the GRASS GIS manual, I have noted that breaking lines should be followed by removing duplicates. Since I have added the -c flag, it seems that duplicates should be removed. Could the extra features be duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your impression is correct. Often non-topological line datasets will have lines crossing with no node at that intersection. `v.clean` with the `break` tool will split the crossed line, thus creating additional line segments. So you should update the segment lengths after doing the `v.clean`.

Furthermore changing the threshold will, of course, change which dangles are removed, and which are left. You should add a threshold for each tool, even though `break` does not need a threshold. So your thresh value should be three numbers: "0,1,7" (or whatever you choose).